# RDLC Reporting Hiding the blank response column

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am trying to show the empty record which is coming from a Server Response. In that response object there is a data array object and in that data array object there is a record array object.In the record there are properties for the fields that I am using in the rdlc to view. So if there is no record I am dynamically assigning the fields (data type string) to string.empty. So What's happening is rdlc is working fine but its displaying a empty box below the header labels in the table. I dont want to display empty row instead I want to display nothing below the table headers. Is there any expression to hide the empty row in a table?

Answer (score 4):

In the 'property' of the Row there is one option visibility....there are three option like true, false and expression ...then select expression ..you can assign the values like

```
 =IIF(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Fields!Fieldname.Value), False,True)
```

Comment: Note that this expression is for the Hidden attribute (not visible). So, for example you'd probably want =IIF(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Fields!Fieldname.Value), True, False) so that the label is hidden when the field is empty (I just got caught by this one)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to msdn site where they explain controlling visibility of elements of a report using rdlc

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd354976.aspx

Let me know if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you can hide column in matrix by using this expression

```
=IIF(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Fields!coumnname.Value), true,false)
```